# nullpointerexception when not taking photo

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have an app where at an activity I am taking a photo (among other things) .

Now, when I press the button to take the photo it opens the camera.If i will press the back button or the cancel button (not taking photo) ,it crashes and gives

> nullpointer

and

> Failure delivering result ResultInfo

in this line:

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

I use:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 

                      if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST){      


                            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                            blobvalue = stream.toByteArray();

                             Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                             Intent k=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);  
                             extras.putParcelable("Bitmap", photo);
                             k.putExtras(extras);

                      }

                      if (requestCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {    

                      }        


           }
```

and in my adapter:

```
ImageView myImage=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myimage);

            final Bitmap image;
            if(theItems.getImagemyItems() != null)
            {
                byte []temp = theItems.getImagemyItems();
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(temp, 0, temp.length);
                myImage.setImageBitmap(image);
            }
            else
            {
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                myImage.setImageBitmap(image);
            }
```

As far as I remember , the above used to workd for this purpose.
I don't know what else to do.

Comment: can u post the stacktrace.

Comment: you are not testing resultCode to know if the user pressed back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just tested requestCode but haven't resultCode so I would suggest you to check resultCode whether user has captured image or cancel capturing.

Try:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST){  
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
        }
        else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
        }
    }
```

Comment: @George Please don't comment which is not related to answer.

Comment: :Ok , for the RESULT_CANCELED should I leave it empty?

Comment: @George It depends on your requirement, if you don't want to do anything when user press back key then don't write anything.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to place a check in your `onActivityResult` , the case `RESULT_OK` is when the user takes the picture successfully and the case `RESULT_CANCELLED` is when you press the hardware back button and want to return to your activity.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
   if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST){      
      if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
      // your code comes here
      }
      if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){  
      }
   }
}
```